# req.params.id giving a colon before 24 digit hex code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
app.post("/campsites/:id/comments", function(req, res){
Campsites.findById(req.params.id.substring(1,), function(err, campsite){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else{
        console.log("Campsite found");
        Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment){
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            else{
                console.log("Comment Created");
                campsite.comments.push(comment);
                console.log("Comment Pushed");
                campsite.save();
                console.log("Campsite Updated");
                res.redirect("/campsites/" + campsite._id);
                console.log("Redirected");
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

req.params.id is returning a colon before id which is why I have to use a substring. Any idea why  this is?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code that's generating the URL leading to this endpoint, the most likely explanation is that your URL includes that colon. If you're new to Express -- the colon used in defining your routes is only used by Express's parser to indicate that that part of the URL is variable and should be named according to what comes after the colon. You replace the entire `:variable-name` part of a URL with the value, not just the part after the colon, for sending requests to that endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that  while sending the data to url you should not include colon in that
eg:
route
app.get("/getTrekData/:trekName")
the url should be
http://localhost:3000/getTrekData/Ooty
it should not be
http://localhost:3000/getTrekData/:Ooty

Answer (score 0):

you may should try this to accept two params from a single request.

```
app.post("/campsites/:id/:comments", function(req, res){

//your code

}
```

and access both as `req.params`. parameterName
If that doesn't work, try using `console.log(req.params)` to see what it is giving you

**if you want to take the comment as body element then not need to specify it into `URL`, the code may be**

```
app.post("/campsites/:id", function(req, res){

//your code

}
```

and access as `req. params.id` and `req.body.commets`
and make sure the value by `console` both.